# Point of the semicolon in this shellshock attack

Tags: echo, shellshock

I was reviewing a shellshock attack and didn't understand this piece of code:

```
curl -v http://localhost/cgi-bin/shellshock.cgi -H "custom:() { ignored; }; echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd "
```

The part that I don't understand is the function of the `echo ;` in the actually executed command on the remote machine between echoing the Content-Type and /bin/cat on /etc/passwd.

What is the function of `echo ;` here?

Thanks.

Comment: This `echo` produces an empty line required by HTTP specification, which separates the headers from the body. But why is it all under the `-H` switch?

Comment: @tomasz, I think your answer was correct and you should undelete it. `-H` is how you get curl to pass a custom header through, which is how the vulnerability works.

Comment: @tomasz, IIRC, custom HTTP headers like that show up as environment variables to a CGI script, and the issue with Shellshock is exactly that Bash executes code from envvars that start with the `()` marker (`custom` being the name of the header here). So, the code to be executed has to be part of the header, and hence within the argument to `-H`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how HTTP is built. There has to be an empty line after the HTTP header. That's what the lonely `echo` produces.

Compare these two:

```
echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd
```

and:

```
echo Content-Type: text/html; /bin/cat /etc/passwd
```

Now it should be obvious as for `echo ;`. (The semicolon separates commands of course.)

Comment: The real question is why isn't it Content-Type: text/plain. I'm going to make my /etc/passwd into a javascript exploit! Eat that!